# Constantly scanning directory for special files to save them upon appearance

Tags: python, bash, centos

I have to deal with some problems when running a quantum chemical program. This program seems to create two important files while it is running, but deletes them directly again after using them. Those files are important to get support on this. But they get deleted too fast and I am not able to copy them by hand.

As there seems to be no way to tell the program that it should save those files I was thinking about a small script that constantly scans the working directory for those files. When they are created, I want that program to copy them to another directory or just to another filename.

Despite the tags that I gave this question, any programming language that is accessible to "CentOS release 6.3 (Final)"-normal users without special rights is ok.

---

I was thinking about doing this by a while loop that containts `find -name ...`  and echoing if files were found/copied. But this approach seems stupid to me and I hope for some input on better solutions.

The files that I want to save are `filename.gcp.in.tmp` and `filename.gcp.out.tmp`.

Comment: By "permanently" do you mean "constantly" ?

Comment: @khelwood Indeed ... sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful trick for grabbing temporary files is to create hard links to them.  That works better than copying because it doesn't matter how big the temporary files are, and there is no danger of missing some of the contents by copying before the file is complete.  When the program that created a temporary file deletes it, the hard link gets left behind.

If you don't know the names of the temporary files in advance, and you can't use `inotify`, one possible way to do it is to run this polling loop in the directory where the files are created:

```
while : ; do
    for tmpfile in *.gcp.in.tmp *.gcp.out.tmp ; do
        [[ -e $tmpfile ]] || continue
        backupfile=$tmpfile.bak
        [[ -e $backupfile ]] || ln -- "$tmpfile" "$backupfile"
    done
done
```

If you know the filenames in advance, and the program that creates them just opens them for writing, closes them, and deletes them, you can do without the loop.  Do this before running your program:

```
touch filename.gcp.in.tmp filename.gcp.out.tmp
ln filename.gcp.in.tmp filename.gcp.in.tmp.bak
ln filename.gcp.out.tmp filename.gcp.out.tmp.bak
```

The contents of the temporary files should be in the `.bak` files when the program has finished running.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inotify for that, and [it seems to be built into CentOS 6.3](https://serverfault.com/a/489050/181073).

For instance (taken from [a tutorial where you'll find more details](http://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/)):

```
while true #run indefinitely
do 
inotifywait -r -e modify,attrib,close_write,move,create,delete /dir && /bin/bash backup-script
done
```

`backup-script` is whatever you'd use to verify the creation of the files you want and copy them elsewhere. You can also use [incron](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-monitor-filesystem-events-with-incron/).

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, but using `inotifywait` from the console tells me that it is not found. Probably I need to install it(?) which is not possible.

Comment: You might have to install the inotify-tools package, but I just noticed that in the tutorial I linked to they installed it from the EPEL repository.